# I thought that i can print value of variable by using its actual address . but i can't instead address is being printed

Tags: c, pointers, printf, dereference

```
int num,address ;
address = &num ;  
num = 2029 ;
printf("\n%d",address) ;
```

It is printing the *address* of num but address of num is being printed.

Is it possible to print value of variable by *accessing its address* not by name like we do in the `scanf()` function?

Comment: To begin with `address = &num` is wrong you cannot assign an address to an `int`, but it may kind of work on certain platforms and evironments. And yes, it's pretty normal it prints the address, because that's what you're asking printf to do.

Comment: Could you elaborate why you would expect that some automatic dereferencing is done? Especially why would a non-pointer type be dereferenced without you explicitely requesting it?

Answer (score 2):

To output a variable value using the variable address you should write for example

```
int num = 2029;
int *address = &num;
printf( "\n%d",*address) ;
```

That is you need a pointer that will store the address of the variable and to get access to the variable itself you need to dereference the pointer.

Or if you want to use integer types then you can do the following

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main( void ) 
{
    int num = 2029;
    uintptr_t address = ( uintptr_t )( void * )&num;

    printf( "num = %d\n", *( int * )( void * )address );
}
```

From the C Standard (7.20.1.4 Integer types capable of holding object pointers)

> The following type designates an unsigned integer type with the
> property that any valid pointer to void can be converted to this type,
> then converted back to pointer to void, and the result will compare
> equal to the original pointer:

```
uintptr_t
```

The same is valid for the type `intptr_t`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a *pointer*:

```
int num, *address; // declares address as a *pointer* to int
address = &num;    // assigns the address of num to address variable
num = 2029;        
printf( "%d\n", *address ); // we *dereference* the address variable
                            // to access the contents of num
```

A *pointer* is any expression whose value is the location of an object or function in a running program's execution environment (i.e., an address).  A pointer *variable* can be used to store the address of another object or function.

A simple pointer variable is declared as

```
T *ptr; // for any type T
```

The type of the variable `ptr` is "pointer to `T`", or `T *`, which is specified by the *combination* of the type specification `T` and the *declarator* `*ptr`.  The "pointer-ness" of the variable is specified by the presence of the `*` operator in the declarator.

Because whitespace isn't significant in this case, you can declare that pointer as any of<sup>1</sup>

```
T *ptr;
T* ptr;
T*ptr;
T      *         ptr;
```

but it will always be parsed as

```
T (*ptr);
```

In the code above we declare `address` as a pointer to `int`:

```
int num, *address;
```

The "`int`-ness" of `address` is provided by the type specifier `int` and the "pointer-ness" of `address` is provided by the declarator `*address`.

The unary `&` operator is used to obtain a pointer value - in the statement

```
address = &num;
```

the *expression* `&num` yields a pointer to the variable `num`.  The type of the expression `&num` is `int *` (pointer to `int`).  The type of the *variable* `address` is also `int *`.

```
 address == &num // int * == int *
```

To access the value stored in `num` from `address`, we *dereference* `address` using the unary `*` operator:

```
printf( "%d\n", *address );
```

The *expression* `*address` has type `int`, and acts as a kinda-sorta alias for the variable `num`:

```
*address == num // int == int
```

Pointer types and declarations can get arbitrarily complex:

```
T *aptr[N];     // aptr is an array of pointers to T
T (*ptra)[N];   // ptra is a pointer to an array of T
T *fptr();      // fptr is a function returning a pointer to T
T (*ptrf)();    // ptrf is a pointer to a function returning T

T *(*(*p[N])())[M] // p is an array of pointers to functions returning
                   // pointers to M-element arrays of pointers to T
```

In both declarations and expressions, the unary `*` operator has lower precedence than the postfix `[]` and `()` operators, so `*a[i]` will be parsed as `*(a[i])` and `*f()` will be parsed as `*(f())` (we're dereferencing the results of `a[i]` and `f()`).

---

1. C++ programmers tend to use the convention `T* ptr;`, because they want to emphasize that `ptr` has pointer type.  However, it is always interpreted by the compiler as `T (*ptr);`.

   I will spare you my usual rant on the practice.

Comment: Out of curiosity, when you have `printf( "\n%d",*address) ;`, how does `printf` know (at an assembly level) to dereference the pointer? Put another way, how does the function tell what is an address that needs to be read from versus a literal number?

Comment: @puppydrum64: It doesn't.  The expression `*address` is evaluated and the *result* of that evaluation is what gets passed to `printf`.

Comment: Duh! I feel silly even for asking.

Comment: @puppydrum64:  Don't. It's not a silly question. But this is what "pass by value" means - when you call a function like `foo( a, b, c );`, each of the *expressions* `a`, `b`, and `c` are fully evaluated and the results of those evaluations are what get passed to the function.